# My css3 animation in google is working but its is not working on firefox

Tags: html, css

here is the css3 code I made and it doesnt run on firefox

```
@keyframes moveobject {
    0%   {top: 0px; background: red; width: 100px;}
    100% {top: 200px; background: yellow; width: 300px;}
}
```

Comment: I just made a jsfiddle with your code and it works fine in Firefox.  http://jsfiddle.net/57xarc6q/  I was going to suggest vendor prefixes, but they've been supported for a while http://caniuse.com/#search=css-animation

Comment: it does move on firefox sir.. now it is not working in google chrome :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add vendor prefixes

```
@-webkit-keyframes moveobject {
    0%   {top: 0px; background: red; width: 100px;}
    100% {top: 200px; background: yellow; width: 300px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes moveobject {
    0%   {top: 0px; background: red; width: 100px;}
    100% {top: 200px; background: yellow; width: 300px;}
}

@keyframes moveobject {
    0%   {top: 0px; background: red; width: 100px;}
    100% {top: 200px; background: yellow; width: 300px;}
}


-webkit-animation: moveobject 5s infinite;
-moz-animation: moveobject 5s infinite;
animation: moveobject 5s infinite;
```

or use [prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) by lea verou